# How to parse a HTML template from Json and populate the data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a requirement to show an HTML template served from a JSON API, with custom tags on it. Those custom tags should be populated with another JSON object. Please help.

I'm able to populate the HTML in the page, but not able to bind the custom variable with a JSON value in it.

Eg:

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

const DynamicContainer = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  let HTML3 = '';
  let title = '';

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/data`)
    .then(res => {
      setResult({
        jsonContent:res.jsonContent,
        jsonHtml:res.jsonHtml
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      setResult({error})
    });
  }, []);

  if(result != "") {
    title = result.jsonContent.title
    HTML1 = result.jsonHtml;
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {ReactHtmlParser(HTML1)}
    </div>

  //<div className="" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: result.jsonHtml}}></div>
  )
}

export default DynamicContainer;
```

// JSON format (
somewhat similar to this JSON format, having an HTML template and a JSON value
This is in my local, in production, there would be 2 APIs serving HTML and JSON.
) :

```
{
  [
    "jsonHTMl":{
      "<div class=\"card \"><h1>${title}</h1></div>"
    },
    "jsonContent": {
      "title": "Hello World"
    }
  ]
}
```

................ New API ................
I have a single HTML template served from an API and multiple array values to populate in the same HTML structure. How to handle this in react js.
{

```
"all_events": [
  {
    "events_value":[
      
    {
      "event_id": 100,
      "title": "Webinar Professionals's Tech Stack",
      "image": "../assets/webinar.png",
      "date": "12/02/2021",
      "description":"Dummy text is text that  "

  },
  {
    "event_id": 101,
      "title": "Boy and Girl Website",
      "image": "../assets/webinar.png",
      "date": "22/03/2021",
      "description":"If the distribution of "

  }
    ],
    "events_template":["<div class=\"card shadow-sm\" id=${event_id}>\n<img src=${image} class=\"img-fluid mw-md-150 mw-lg-130 mb-6 mb-md-0\" alt=\"...\" />\n<div class=\"card-body\">\n<h3 class=\"card-text\">${title}</h3>\n<p class=\"card-text\">On ${date}</p>\n<p class=\"card-text\">${description}</p>\n<div class=\"text-center\">\n<a href=\"/event/${event_id}\" className='mt-4 btn btn-primary'>\n Details\n</a>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>"]
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Could you post some server url to fetch the data. We can not fetch data from: http://localhost:3000/data

Answer (score 0):

[lodash](https://lodash.com/) has a simple template engine [template](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template).

```
const compiled = _.template(result.jsonHtml);
const html = compiled(result.jsonContent)
```

For new api

```
data["all_events"].forEach(events => {
    const templates = events["events_template"];
    const values = events["events_value"];
    templates.forEach(template => {
        values.forEach(value => {
            const compiled = _.template(template);
            const html = compiled(value)
            // html is the processed result. Perhaps you want collect them to an array?
        })
    })
})
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-chatterjee-cnlr9?file=/src/App.js) link.

Comment: How to load the above code it the json  contains an array of value.How to use a looping like ForEach etc..

Comment: Please give a example.

Comment: Something similar to the above react code. One template and array of values..API looks like: {

  "all_events": [
    {
      "events_value":[
        
      {
        "event_id": 100,
        "title": "Webinar",
        "date": "12/02/2021"

    }
    {
      "event_id": 102,
        "title": "Webinars Professionals",
        "date": "27/05/2021"

    }
      ],
      "events_template":["<div id=${event_id}>\n<div class=\"card-body\">\n<h3 class=\"card-text\">${title}</h3>\n<p class=\"card-text\">On ${date}</p>\n</div>"]
    }
  ]

}

Comment: Please edit in the question with a more readable format.

Comment: Hi @vipcxj- sorry for the format issue. Ive updated the question area with new API details. The react code is the same or can modify

Comment: right now it's printing  "html" as  [object Object].

Comment: Thank you @vipcxj for putting the code in the sandbox. That helped me.